# why my php code for injection isnt working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection

I write simple php script with mysql to try sql injection and it isn't working.

Here is my sql query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$userId'";
echo 'QUERY '. $sql .'<br>';
$userQ = mysql_query($sql);
$user = mysql_fetch_array($userQ);
```

I try to go to this url

```
http://localhost/SQL%20In/inside.php?id=apie&userId=1;%20DROP%20TABLE%20users
```

and it isnt doing anything

Comment: `mysql_` can't execute multiple queries in one statement. SQL injection you *can* do is `' OR 1=1 --`

Comment: Mysqli cant execute multiple queries

Comment: Neither `mysql_` or `mysqli_` can execute multiple queries in one go. They have to be done separately, which is why the `' DROP TABLE users;--` injection won't work. But stuff like `' OR 1=1;--` would work, so you still have to use a prepared statement - and for the love of all that is holy, not be using `mysql_` :-)

Comment: Can you help me by telling me how i can make it possible to execute such queries in php? Or is it completly imposible?

Comment: Using `mysql_` its not possible, as they can only handle one query at a time. The `mysqli_` library has `mysqli_multi_query()`, which could do it.

Comment: I tried it with multi query but it isnt working with fetch array

Comment: When you use multi-query, the query has multiple result sets, so you have to do an extra loop to iterate through the results. See the code example in the docs here: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php